# SQL Perform an Action on Every Row that Meets Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

[Here is the sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/682a10/2)

I am currently trying to average rent over a particular zip code wildcard. For example, if the zipcode for 20000 has rent value 0, it will instead insert the average rent for (non-zero) zipcodes matching the '20%' wildcard. Currently, however, it is averaging all of the rents, regardless of the wildcard. Here is what I am getting:

```
rent    zip
2375    20000
1000    20001
2000    20002
5000    30000
1500    20003
2375    30001
```

but this is what I want:

```
rent    zip
1500    20000
1000    20001
2000    20002
5000    30000
1500    20003
5000    30001
```

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT IF(tmp.rent=0, 
          (select AVG(rent) from tmp where rent > 0 and zip LIKE CONCAT(substr(zip,1,2),'%')), 
          tmp.rent) as rent, 
       zip 
from tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

won't this expression evaluate to TRUE for all non-null values of zip, in other words, "all of them" ?

```
 zip LIKE CONCAT(substr(zip,1,2),'%'))
```

Seems like you want to *qualify* one of those the column references so it refers to a column from the outer query. It's good practice to qualify *all* column references.

```
SELECT IF( t.rent=0
         , ( SELECT AVG(s.rent)
               FROM tmp s
              WHERE s.rent > 0
                AND s.zip LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTR(t.zip,1,2),'%')
           )
         , t.rent
       ) AS rent
     , t.zip 
  FROM tmp t
```